# Where is the work in the GIS/RS consulting industry?

Tags: industry, gis-professional, freelancing

I'm trying to get an understanding of what type of GIS/RS work organizations are most often bidding out to consultants, and why?  For example, is most of the freelance work in web mapping these days because in-house programmers have not caught up with this rapidly expanding field?  Maybe all the work involves niche specialty jobs, such as GIS/RS research support for temporary environmental projects because non-profit organizations do not have the expertise.  Perhaps, oil and gas jobs are dominating the freelance market because of the fracking boom.

**What type of GIS/RS work are private/corporate/governmental organizations most often bidding out to consultants these days, and why?**

Comment: Because it's unlikely that an authoritative or well-referenced answer to this question is possible, I am making it CW to increase the latitude for personal and speculative answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

I can only offer a completely unscientific assessment of what I personally see as a freelancer in the UK, which may be completely unrepresentative (and I would be most interested in the replies of other freelancers on the forum).  So, in descending order starting with the most common:

- Programming (C# and .NET especially and surprisingly little Python)
- Web mapping (Java and ASP seem most desired)
- Data management (ArcServer and Oracle Spatial most requested unsurprisingly)
- Oil & Gas geo-processing using proprietary oil-industry software and usually requiring  knowledge of oil-industry work-flows and geological data.

*EDIT (2020):  Since I wrote this many years ago, I have seen a steady rise in the demand for Python, PostGIS and QGIS.*

There is then a jump down in skill level to:

- Data collection and digitization (not so much of the latter as most of this work gets sent to sweat shops in India and China for a fraction of the price.  These are places where time and motion studies are down to individual mouse clicks to maintain the competitive edge.
- Mapping - ok so it's contentious listing this as a lower grade skill I'll grant you - I am liable to be lynched by cartographers but this is arguably something any GIS professional *can* do (irrespective of whether they do it well) and it seems to pay less than programming.

Next there are the niche jobs, which I can't possibly list as they are many and varied and I probably don't even know about half of them.  This is where I get most of my income (especially 3D landscape modelling and wind farm related analysis), but that's a reflection of personal interest and skill set rather than the market per se.

Over the last 15 to 20 years I have seen a dramatic increase in the number of GIS jobs being advertised, especially in the last five years, whether contract or permanent.  A lot of organisations have GIS professionals in-house now across all business sectors.  What I find is that I am often providing services to companies who have access to bigger GIS firms (or firms with bigger GIS departments) but those firms are over-stretched, too generalised or I'm able to offer a skill that goes beyond the normal rank-and-file GIS professional (i.e. within my niches).  Most of the contracts seem to be let by private business and less by government/councils.  This may be due to the different cultures, where private business is more comfortable/used to using contractors.

The other thing I am starting to see is a slowly increasing number of requests for FOSS4G related skills.  Without a doubt ESRI and MapInfo seem to be most requested, but a few years ago I would never see anybody asking for skills in QGIS, PostGIS, Mapnik, Openlayers or GeoServer etc.  Now they do sometimes pop up on the radar.

Comment: Great insight here. I'm surprised to hear that C# and .NET are taking the show. Is this because these are your programming languages of choice, or are they requested by the client?

Comment: I'm a scripter not a programmer, so my language of choice is Python and therefore I have to let these jobs go :(  (So, it is the companies letting contracts who are asking for it and not my choice).